# Changing text from 2-lines to 1-line - how to center the text field in a square again?

Tags: inkscape, text, svg, alignment

I am developing [a word game for iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xso29.png) and would like to use [an SVG file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3ABlank_Scrabble_board_with_coordinates.svg) as the gaming board.

The SVG file (author: Denelson83, Wikimedia Commons) is almost perfect for my game - except that I would like to use 1-lined texts (like "3W", "2L", etc.) instead of the 2-lined texts in the original.

So I click a colored square that I'd like to change and then press SHIFT-D to jump to the original group.

Then I change the 2-lined text to a 1-lined text (in the screenshot below it is "3W" in the red square):

[image: screenshot]

**My question is:** how to center-align (both vertically and horizontally) the text again?

Or as alternative: make the text field fill its parent at 100% width and height?

**UPDATE:**

I've found the Alignment dialog, but what to select there?

Clicking the 3rd icon in the 1st and 2nd row doesn't change anything:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't align an object with itself. You can only align objects to each other. So if you're going to use the align tools, you need to select your text AND the box you are aligning it to, then apply the filters.

Another option is to make your text box the exact same height and width as your background box and then use the text tool's alignment features instead to align the text within its own text box.

(PS. remember the conditions of the license. You'll have to release your own game under the same CC license if you use this artwork.)

Comment: No, I don't think, I have to release the game under same license - but just the modified artwork (can put it on a website, with attribution to the author): http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en

Comment: That might be correct. Alas, I always get confused with CC licenses. They always seem sufficiently vague enough to leave way too many questions. :)

Comment: +1 so true, I'd like to attribute to the author, but it is so unclear how to do it correctly (just mention his name? add a link in my app?)

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking, you should put his name in the app (just think how feature movies have hundreds of names), and a link to the original art wherever you make your art available. Also note that as this have a `share alike` you are required to redistribute your modified board, with the same licensing terms - placing a link to these resources, possibly in an "about" screen of the app would be a way to comply.